# Rails 3.2.13 Javascript Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am working on a `Rails 3.2.13` app, and encountering the following problem:

The Javascript files I wrote in the app/assets/javascripts/  directory don't seem to be run.

I have JS code in a file called **menu_list.js**  in the app/assets/javascripts/ directory, but it does not do anything.  Whereas when I put the same code on the view page in a  tag, it works.

```
<script>$("#sortable").sortable();</script>
```

Here's my **application.js** file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require_tree .
```

my **menu_list.js**  file:

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

It does not make sense to me, as I thought `//= require_tree .` would include all the javascript files in the directory.  I tried other javascript files too, but they don't seem to have any effects.

Comment: Are you seeing your script tags for menu_list.js being created in the generated html markup? It's my understanding that = require includes the javascript in the manifest but doesn't necessarily include it on the page.

Comment: should I be looking for something like <script src="/javascripts/menu_list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>?  In that case, no, it's not there in the html markup

Comment: Do you have $(document).ready in your javascript?

Comment: @John Yeung - yes. are you including the file in your app using a javascript_include_tag?

Comment: yes, my code in the javascript is as shown in the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

If this truly is all you have in `app/assets/javascripts/menu_list.js` it will run as soon as the script is loaded, which is *not* what you want. You want to run the above code at least after the DOM has fully loaded into the page and not before.

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

If the environment you're running in is `:development`, and you properly have the following in your layout

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

you will see a separate `<script>` tag for every Javascript file Sprockets is loading. The `//= require_tree .` *will* pick up your `app/assets/javascripts/menu_list.js` file.

I suggest also making sure you don't have any precompiled version of your assets in place by running the following in shell

```
rake assets:clean
```

You can also force debug mode *(individual `<script>` tags for each file)* by adding a `:debug` option to the above include tag

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", debug: true %>
```

Comment: i tried all of the above, but no luck...And when I tried to manually include the javascript <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "menu_list" %>, the mark up <script src="/javascripts/menu_list.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is generated, but there's no effect.

Comment: The include take you showed makes no sense. Also, a path like `/javascripts/menu_list.js` makes no sense. The path should be `/assets/menu_list.js`

Comment: sorry that was my desperate attempt to make it work. as for the second part of your comment, aren't javascripts located in '/assets/javascripts/'?

Comment: When assets are served by the asset pipeline the URLs are `/assets/...`; there is no `assets/javascripts/` or `assets/stylesheets` folder created. For example, see **[this screenshot](http://take.ms/0MHDp)** from one of my Rails apps in development.

Comment: hi @Deefour, I spent another day trying to figure out what's wrong. but I can't seem to understand why my layouts/application.html.erb is displaying this: <link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>, as opposed to your screenshot. What would be some possibilities as to why it's happening? It'd great if you can point me to a direction to work in. Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I would do is upgrade your application to 3.2.13 or 3.2.14 (it's in RC2 now, nearing release).

Comment: oops, turns out it's already version 3.2.13, i made an error in the original post. One thing to note is when I ran 'rails -v' in the app directory it shows 'Rails 3.2.13' but when I ran it in the C:/users/user directory it shows Rails 4.0.0. Would this have contributed to the problem?

Comment: Nope, I run 4.0 and the behavior is the same. I suggest next you try with a fresh rails install *(I'm just making guesses now)* - maybe the behavior is coming from a gem?

Comment: I removed all the gems and ran [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) and bundle install, no luck.

Comment: here's what I did and worked - started a new rails project and copied everything over. Thanks for all your help @Deefour!

Answer (score 0):

Most common cause for this is that the call to `javascript_include_tag` that is on the default layout, then you create another layout, forget to add the include there and then nothing works in controllers where you use this new layout.

Comment: I only have one layout file though - application.html.erb.  Can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: it's simple. You're loading all your dependencies in this application.js file, but nowhere does Rails automatically load this application.js file for you. Usually, it's explicitly loaded in your layout. If you create a new layout, you must load it from there too in order to have all your js. In your case, if you only have one layout, check that you're loading it from that layout.

Comment: doesn't <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> already do that though?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does.